# Request tag synonym tag:adverse-possesion -> tag:adverse-possession

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

The tag [adverse-possesion](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverse-possesion) is misspelled. I have re-tagged the newest question with a properly spelled [adverse-possession](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverse-possession).

Could someone create a tag synonym to point from [adverse-possesion](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverse-possesion) to [adverse-possession](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverse-possession) and [merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet/119377#119377) (I think a moderator has to do this part) [adverse-possesion](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverse-possesion) into [adverse-possession](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverse-possession)?